# Reading data from a SQL database and putting that data straight into an object using java

Tags: java, sql, database

Hi i was wondering is there a way of copying all the rows from a SQL database straight into an a separate object for each row?

Comment: What do you exactly mean because there are ORM tools, like Hibernate, that can do that for you. Hibernate is easy to learn and it converts the data rows in the database into pure Java objects that are in accord with your tables.

Comment: I have a database of patient (including a: id, name, address and phone) I then have an object Patient(with an arraylist of patients) and i want my program to load all the patients stored in the database to my object patient one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM is the best way to map database entities to objects, e.g. Hibernate. Here is example how to use Hibernate: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2004/jw-1018-hibernate.html

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html

RowSet is your friend ... and now I have 30 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use [JPA](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html). You need to define the table column mapping to the POJO and use one of the query api's provided.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the easies way is to use Hibernate and Spring.

If you correctry configure these two frameworks, you will be able to get util.List of your objects in one simple row of code.
Here is perfect tutorial by mkyong: 
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-mysql-example/

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

[JPA](https://confluence.jayway.com/login.action?os_destination=/display/jayway/Conferences%2bPlan#ConferencesPlan-2013), [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) and [JdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate) are some suggestions that comes to mind.